# VirtualBox refuses to start VM

Tags: virtualbox, 14.10, virtualization

I have created a VM in VirtualBox, but have not yet bean able to install an OS on it, because every time that I click the `Start` button in the VirtualBox interface I get these errors:

[image: First error]

[image: Second error]

I have tried creating a new VM several times now, but still the same error, what can I do to fix this?

VirtualBox package information:

```
virtualbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.18-dfsg-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.3.18-dfsg-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     4.3.18-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

OS information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms build-essential
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: The first command gave this output: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version.
dkms set to manually installed.
linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic set to manually installed.
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`.

Comment: And the second command's output was (and it still hasn't seemed to finish, although there is no more output): `Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS`.

Comment: But it still does not fix my problem, and I still get the same errors when trying to start a VM in VirtualBox.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv start`

Comment: The output of that command is: `Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.`

Comment: Oh and by the way the second command just finished with its output, which was (the completed output): `Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.`.

Comment: Oh, and now after running the command `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv start` it seems to have fixed my problem! Thanks! :)

Comment: It should start automatically though, could you try a reboot and see if it works?

Comment: Ok, I have now rebooted, and all is working as it should now without the need for me to do anything special, so thanks again! :)